# Retrieving previously deleted polygon features

Tags: qgis, features

I've been working on a network route on QGIS 3.22.6 for the past few weeks now, as I've been going through and deleting some overlaid features, I must have accidentally deleted a boundary that I needed.

I don't know when I did it.

Is there a way to retrieve a feature that's been deleted in the past?

Answer (score 3):

If your data storage has backups you could use those to restore a previous version of the file/table.

Otherwise you'll have to redo the work.